# zeep's AsyncClient does not seem to be working as intended

Tags: python, python-asyncio, zeep

I'm trying to use zeep's AsyncClient to do asynchronous pulls and I don't seem to be getting the asynchronous aspect of it as intended. I understand on some level that the AsyncClient is synchronous due to the WSDL load but I don't think that explains the behavior that I'm currently seeing. I've tried various set-ups within my code to get the desired behavior but I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to utilize it

Here's what my code looks like, boiled down to the necessities:

```
import azure.storage.blob.aio as blob
import asyncio
import datetime
import time
import zeep
from zeep.transports import AsyncTransport
import zeep.helpers
import httpx
import logging
logging.getLogger('zeep.wsdl.bindings.soap').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

async def gather_with_concurrency(n, *coros):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)
    async def sem_coro(coro):
        async with semaphore:
            return await coro
    return await asyncio.gather(*(sem_coro(c) for c in coros))
async def get_location_data(access_token,locations,businessdate,aclient,transport,blob_client):
    transport.client.headers.update({'AccessToken': access_token,'LocationToken':locations[1]})
    aclient.service._binding_options.update({'address':'actual_address_for_calls'})
    req_type = aclient.get_type('OperationName')
    #Include parameters in request body
    req_data = req_type(BusinessDate=businessdate)
    data = await aclient.service.OperationName(req_data)
    ###
    Add extra points to data for better tracking
    ###
    json_data = zeep.helpers.serialize_object(data)
   

 await blob_client.upload_blob(json.dumps(json_data,default=str),overwrite=True)
    print(f'Finished getting data for {locations[0]} at {time.time()-ref}')
    return json_data
async def main():
    ###
    Get credentials needed to establish connections and grab location tokens/access token
    ###   
    tasks = []
    businessdate = datetime.date(2023,3,7)
    wsdl_client = httpx.Client()
    async_client = httpx.AsyncClient()    
    transport= AsyncTransport(client=async_client,wsdl_client=wsdl_client)
    aclient = zeep.AsyncClient("Link.to.WSDL",transport=transport)    
    print('Getting Location Data')
    for location in location_tokens:
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='container_name',blob=f'blob_name')
        async with blob_client:
            tasks.append(get_location_data(access_token,location,businessdate,aclient,transport,blob_client))
    location_data = await gather_with_concurrency(30,*tasks)
    

ref = time.time()
loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Although the above works when the response is small amounts of data (~20 Kib), the run time is more pronounced when the response is larger (~2 MiB).

Is there something I'm missing to using the AsyncClient?